# How to pass an id @click on vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to pass `id` by `this.id` parameter but I can´t send and receive it. How can I send `this.id` for parameter on vue.js?

```
<button 
    id="txt"
    @click="activate(this.id)"
    class="kind-btn"
    type="button"
>
    <i class='fas   fa-poll-h kind-icon'></i>
</button>
<button
    id="pic"
    @click="activate(this.id)"
    class="kind-btn"
    type="button"
    style="padding-left: 15px;"
>
    <i class='fas fa-image kind-icon'style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
</button>
<button
    id="sound"
    @click="activate(this.id)"
    class="kind-btn"
    type="button"
>
    <i class="material-icons kind-icon"style="font-size: 31px;top: 8px;margin-bottom: 13px;">music_video</i>
</button>
```

// js

```
activate: function(i) {
  console.log(i);
  switch (i) {
    case "txt":
      $("#" + this).css({"background-color": "#fe5d87", "color": "white"});
      break;

    case "pic":
      $("#" + this).css({"background-color": "#fe5d87", "color": "white"});
      break;

    case "sound":
      $("#" + this).css({"background-color": "#fe5d87", "color": "white"});
      break;
    // 
    // default:
    //   $("#txt").css({"background-color": "#fe5d87", "color": "white"});
  }
```

Comment: i wanna pass id by this.id parameter but i cant send and recieve it

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question?

Comment: You can´t refer to the `id` of a button by using `@click="activate(this.id)"`. `this.id` would reffer to a property called `id` in you component.

Answer (score 2):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

You can do @click="activate"

```
methods: {
    activate: function (event) {
        console.log(event.target.id)
    }
}
```

The other way is to pass the event, if you needed to pass more data

```
@click="activate('your custom data string', $event)"
```

Comment: tnks but i wanna use this.id like onclick() method on js not by event or if it was i wanna define vue by this.id not write 'your custom data string'

Comment: like this ..     @click="activate(this.id , $event)"

Comment: @click="activate($event.target.id)"

Comment: @alishamsi You have to understand how vue.js works. As I stated in my comment at your question, you can´t use `this.id` like that. This here is a good answer.